# import pandas could not be resolved

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, visual-studio-code

I am new to python, I have followed a tutorial and installed latest version of anaconda
created an environement by installing python 3.6

used following commands

```
    conda create -n env1 python=3.6
    conda activate env1
    conda install pandas
```

but when I am running the code I am getting following error and I am not able to identify what is going wrong with the code.

[image]

VS code:

[image]

Edit #1:

Just to test with other version, I have installed python 3.7 and run the following code

[image]

Comment: `conda activate env1`. As well, check out output of `which python`

Comment: @SergeyBushmanov env1 is already activated in command prompt and in the bottom left of the VS code I have selected env1 as interpreter

Answer (score 0):

```
conda create -n env1 python=3.6
conda activate env1
conda install pandas
```

Comment: I am sorry, I should have mentioned in my question. I have activated it before running pandas/ I have editied my question now

Comment: Looks like numpy isn't installed, which is strange because it gets installed while installing pandas. Could you try `conda install numpy` ?

Comment: It says - # All requested packages already installed.

Comment: Can you create a new env from scratch and try again?

Comment: I did it. With python =3.6, 3.7, 3.8 then activate the environment and then install pandas and they all have same error message. I have also pasted another image where I have tried the same with different version of python.

Comment: @Zerotoinfinity, I'm unable to replicate the error.

Comment: I am very new to python so I don't know what happened here but when I used pip install instead of conda install, everything work smoothly :) I have no idea what is the difference and what happened.

Comment: @Zerotoinfinity, not sure why conda didn't work but pip did. Anyways, glad something worked :)